# python USER_BASE error

Tags: python, django

I am using python 2.6 and trying to install  django tagging package and i get this error below.I am installing few python 2.4 packages on a 64 bit machine which already has python2.6.

How to resolve this error

```
 [root@tom django-tagging-0.3.1]# python setup.py install
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
 from distutils.command.install import INSTALL_SCHEMES
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 21, in <module>
 from site import USER_BASE
 ImportError: cannot import name USER_BASE
```

`EDIT 1`

```
[root@tom django-tagging-0.3.1]# python2.6 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
from distutils.command.install import INSTALL_SCHEMES
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 21, in <module>
from site import USER_BASE
ImportError: cannot import name USER_BASE
```

`EDIT2`

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print(get_python_lib())
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

`EDIT3`

```
>>> import site ; print site
<module 'site' from '/opt/mysite/site/__init__.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called one of your Django apps "site". This is shadowing the `site` module in the stdlib. Rename it.